# Android Emulator crashing when saving an reading files

Tags: android, android-listview, android-emulator

I'm trying to save a custom object when I **click** a **menu item**. The problem is its **crashing**. Before we start, when I try to read that data in another activity, that also crashes. Here is my code where I'm trying to save the data:

Here's a pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/ZQTUJKGP).

```
    my write function in the menu

myInfo.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener()
{
  public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
  {
     Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Results.this, listTimes.class);
     ourIntent.putExtra("Meeting", meetingObj);

     try {
     fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
     oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
     oos.writeObject(businesses.get(positionChecked));

     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
     }
      finally
     {
      try {
      oos.close();
      fos.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                }

                                //startActivity(ourIntent);
                                return true;
                        }


// My read function

private void getData()
        {
                try {
                        fis = openFileInput(filename);
                        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                        business = (Business) ois.readObject();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                        try {
                                ois.close();
                                fis.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }

        }
```

Comment: No pastebin. SO. Please move *relevant* code to your question. Also, do you have the correct permissions set in yopur manifest? Please post your StackTrace.

Comment: Erm, I'm a noob here. I can't format my code right in a post. Hence the pastebin. Also, what permissions do I need to read and write from internal storage? I didn't find any, except for external storage.

Comment: When the app crashes, you get a set of lines in your LogCat, could you please post those? (4 spaces before a line put it in code blocks, a `>` before a line puts it in a non formatted text block)

Comment: Give me a second on the logcat.

Comment: :O LogCat is your friend! It tels you exactly where the problem is... Most of the time :)

Comment: There is not enough space to post the logcats

Comment: @user106857 post only the exception part not the entire logcat

Comment: Exceptions part? There are only the verbose, error, warn, assert, debug and info parts.